# Intuition behind Lie algebra being an "infinitesimal transformation"

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, infinitesimals

I have been having some trouble intuitively understanding the "infinitesimal" behavior of a Lie algebra. Currently, I think of Lie groups intuitively being a group of continuous transformations. For example, any element of the Lie group $SO(3)$ corresponds to rotation about some angle $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, I do not know how to interpret the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Based on what I have read any element in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is an "infinitesimal" rotation about some angle $\theta$. But what does this mean exactly?

Comment: It simply means consider the rotations in that direction as $\theta$ varies and differentiate at $\theta =0$

Comment: @Callum Sorry I did not understand, could you elaborate?

Comment: Let $R_\theta$ denote rotation through an angle of $\theta$ in a fixed plane (in $SO(3)$ all rotations are of this form but these idea work in higher dimension). Then $X_\theta \cdot v = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} (R_{t\theta} \cdot v)$ defines an "infinitesimal" action. Indeed we have simply $X_\theta = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} R_{t\theta}$.

Comment: Note "infinitesimal" is just used to describe this process of obtaining the Lie algebra as derivatives of the Lie group. The transformation corresponding is not like a really small rotation. For example, you will find (sort of) 90 degree rotations like $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1& 0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$(not really as the normal direction is sent to 0) in the Lie algebra but also every scale of these and $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2& 0\\-2&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is even less like a rotation. Instead what they are is "in the tangential direction of" a family of rotations.

Comment: @Callum Thank you that was very helpful. So elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ tell us how elements of $SO(3)$ change near the identity by linearizing everything as a derivative does? Based on my readings, this linearization/delinearization is done by the logarithm and exponential function, at least locally. Is this right?

Comment: Yes that is a fair way to describe them. The exponential map here is exactly the map $\exp(X_\theta) = R_\theta$ and in this example it is surjective but not injective. The logarithm is an inverse but we need to either restrict $\exp$ to a subset where it is bijective (indeed a diffeomorphism) or take branch cuts etc.

Comment: @Callum Great, thank you for all your help!